# Get webpage path useing django

Tags: python, django

When user login iwant to redirect him to user page with the same language

This is what i tried to do

```
if   request.path  == '/classgate/log-ar/' :
   messages.success(request,f'مرحبا !{request.user.username} استمتع بوقتك')
   return redirect('user-ar')
elif  request.path == '/classgate/log/' :
   messages.success(request,f'Welcome {request.user.username} enjoy your time')
   return redirect('userr')
```

But when i did it with

```
request.META.get('HTTP-REFERRER')
```

It worked